# Adding randomly generated numbers together in Java

Tags: java

I have a problem I'm trying to work on.

I have this code so far.

```
public class Average {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            int n= Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            int i;
            for(i=1; i<= n; i++){
                System.out.println(Math.random());              
            }
        }
    }
```

This gives me n randomly generated numbers, Yay! But I want to be able to add those numbers together. Can this be done? I'm completely lost.

Comment: How would you do this for *any* numbers? If the answer is "I don't know", start by writing down a process - any process, but it should be about like how you would do this in your head - and then presenting that in the problem, showing that which is unclear.

Comment: I don't seem to understand how Math.random() works. Does it treat all of the numbers as one unit, or all as separate units. If they are separate, then how do I multiply each separate part to themselves.

Comment: [`Math.random()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()) returns a single `double` value, picked .. at random. This value can be assigned to a (double) variable or used an expression (such as in the shown method call).

Comment: I set integer n to a command line argument, and so whatever number I put in there gives me n number of Math.randoms. I want to add those numbers and divide by n. Essentially getting the average of all of the numbers that are generated.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Average {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int n= Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int i;
        double thisRand = 0;
        double result = 1;
        for(i=1; i<= n; i++){
            thisRand = Math.random();
            System.out.println(thisRand);
            result *= thisRand;
        }
    }
}
```

The variable `result` will contain the multiplication of your random values. The `*=` operator multiplies the the values on either side of it, and stores it in the left-hand side variable.

Comment: .. and should result start as 1 rather than 0 ?  ;)

Comment: Haha, oh I am not awake today.

Comment: This seems to have only multiplied the last randomly generated number by 1. I wound up with 5 "random" numbers and then a repeat of the last number.

Comment: Is `double result = 1;` defined before your `for` loop? Furthermore, are you looking at the value of `result` and not `thisRand`?

Comment: My code looks just like your code. As far as my tired eyes can tell.

Comment: My end result is to get the average of n amount of numbers. I've been putting 5 into my command line argument, and getting five numbers. I want to add all of those numbers and divide by n (5 in this case). Is there a way to do this I'm missing?

Comment: You'd want to add rather than multiply in this case. You can use the `+=` operator instead to add them together (and don't forget to reset the initial value of `result` to 0). After the loop, put in something like `double average = result / n;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, you will give two arguments, "number" that is the amount of numbers you want to multiply, and the "result" of multiplying all numbers, hope is what you want. I use recursive programming

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Integer result=1;
      System.out.println(multiplyNumbers(3, result));
   }
   static Integer multiplyNumbers(int number, int result){
        int value = new Random().nextInt(10);
        if (number > 0){
            result = multiplyNumbers(--number, result);
            return result *= value;
        }
        return 1;
    }
```